# Setting LinkCommand property of a grid column during runtime

Tags: acumatica

I know we can set a LinkCommand property for a grid column in design time itself as below

```html
<px:PXGridColumn MatrixMode="True" LinkCommand="ViewDetails" DataField="Value" Width="300px" AllowShowHide="False" AllowSort="False" >
```

However, can we set this property during runtime based on certain business logic.

[image]

With that it creates hyperlink for entire column, I need only for Case number.

Comment: Couldn't you just update the logic within the command to what you need at runtime?

Comment: I want to set a hyperlink for value of one of the attribute in Case screen.

Comment: You should be able to capture the value when calling ViewDetails? if not, what limitations are you running into?

Comment: What do you mean by calling ViewDetails. Can you describe or provide an example

Comment: In your code you have your link command set to call the PXAction ViewDetails which I assumed you wrote or you are wanting to override. This points to the method called when the button is clicked. You can call the name anything you want but "ViewDetails" is commonly used in Acumatica. If you search the Acumatica source for this you will find the usage on many graphs. Hope that helps.

Comment: Understood, I was confused with the name. Have included an image with more description. I need hyperlink only for one of the value in attribute not entire column. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147304/discussion-between-krunal-and-brendan).

Answer (score 1):

There seems no solution to have hyperlink for only one grid cell in Attribute. Hence the solution is to add a button on top of the grid and link that button to have functionality of same action you need for hyperlink.

Comment: To my knowledge LinkCommand isn't flexible enough. It could be possible to use CSS to selectively remove the links but this is not good practice within the framework.